# Mean of vectors

Tags: math, vector

I'm facing what looks like a simple a issue of computing a mean value (average) of vectors.
Looking around for a standard or a definition for calculating a "mean vector" for a group of vectors only taught me that this isn't a straight forward issue so here I'm writing this question.

I have 2 Vectors:

[Amp1,theta1] & 
[Amp2,theta2]

And I would say that my question is:

1. What is a "mean vector" for 2 or more vectors (if such definition exists)?
2. How do I compute one (I guess that If I know 1, I also got 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The respective Cartesian vectors are

(Amp1 * cos theta1, Amp1 * sin theta1) and

(Amp2 * cos theta2, Amp2 * sin theta 2).

Now add the respective coordinates and divide by the number of vectors (2) to get the (arithmetic) mean.

Answer (score 1):

there is not straight forward method to add two vectors which are in [magnitude,argument] form. They need to be converted into Cartesian co-ordinates before adding them up and finding mean.
so, unfortunately the mean **isn't**

```
    [(amp1+amp2)/2,(theta1+theta2)/2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The mean is usually described as the arithemtic mean of 2 or more values (see [Mean](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mean.html)). Based on the definition I would suggest to add all the available vectors and divide the sum vector by the amount of vectors given.

For your example the mean would be calculated like this

```
[(Amp1 + Amp2) / 2, (theta1 + theta2) / 2]
```

And there is usually only one mean value.

Comment: This is correct by scalar definition but in the vector world this doesn't have any meaning. I think that there should be some method that adds the amplitude 'weight' to the angle.